# ASP.Net + C# - If MySQL query returns no rows, do

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, datatable, dataadapter

I've got a function that queries a MySQL table and displays the output in a graph.

However, if no queries are returned, I'd like to output a message in lblError2.  I've tried to use the code below but that doesn't seem to work.  It outputs nothing.

code:

```
protected void chart(int moduleID)
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

    string comm = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE test_id=0 AND module_id=@ModuleID AND user_id=@UserID";
    MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(comm, conn);
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@ModuleID", moduleID));
    mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@UserID", Session["UserID"]));

    MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();

    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "attempt no.";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "%";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal;
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 2;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

        if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Chart1.DataSource = ds;
            Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "score";
            Chart1.DataBind();
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = ds.Rows.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            Chart1.Visible = false;
            lblError2.Text = "No results found.";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error. Unable to obtain data at the moment.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `ds.Rows.Count == 0` and you don't see the message "No results found."?  Are you sure that lblError2.Visible = true?

Comment: what happens after you step thru on this line `dataAdapter.Fill(ds);`

Comment: @RickS lblError2 is definitely true. I think ds.Rows.Count == 0 or it contains one row with all null values. When I execute the sql query in mysql workbench, it returns no rows.

Comment: As DJ KRAZE suggests, why don't you debug this code and step through it?  We can only guess what your problem is...

Comment: Thanks all.  I had to move the lblError2 into a UpdatePanel.